# Is there any plugin/extension/add-on for Mozilla Thunderbird Notifications in GNOME

Tags: gnome, thunderbird, email, notification, ubuntu-gnome

The question is pretty straightforward.

The default notifications by [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) don't really work in GNOME. I have had to install an extension (add-on) called 'Enhanced Desktop Notifications' which does its job but there are few disadvantages.

1. It notifies the same thing twice (i don't really know why).
2. And most importantly, I use GNOME for the excellent **notification panel**(?). These notification doesn't lead me to **Thunderbird** when i click on it. I've had to manually open **Thunderbird**, which imo defeats the purpose of using GNOME.

OS Version - Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 as well as 15.10

GNOME Version - 3.18.4

Thunderbird Version - 38.8.0 (No, this is not a new bug)

PS - Don't tell me to use **[Evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution)**, believe me, I've tried, I still have it too, it just isnt **Thunderbird**, crashes a lot, doesn't look good etc etc. Too bad though, its a really cool **"Information Management Application"**

Comment: Maybe you could use the GNotifier addon ;)